# Remove duplicates commits

Tags: git

Its possible remove these commits duplicates ? [image]

Comment: This history has been merged and pushed and shared. You must not change it.

Comment: Why did you decide to remove commits from history? You can use revert command if you want to roll back changes.

Comment: I was use bitbucket in this merge i don't know it happened exactly. Everything there seemed fine until I migrated to github and noticed a sequence of duplicate commits in the history

Comment: yes it is, but most people will tell you it is a bad idea. If this you show is the history of the remote "blessed" repository that others have access to, you'll need to do a lot of work. I mean mostly `git commit --amend`, `git reset --hard`, `git push -f`. This will result in changing _all_ commits that are descendants of those you remove. And then rebase all local work on top of the new changes. Note: you have to force push all these changes, because you need to be extra sure you want to do this and that it is absolutely, positively mandatory action to perform.

Answer (score 1):

Use [git-revert command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) to roll back changes. It might be a good idea [to create different branch](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) and to try it out there.

Comment: OP is asking to _remove_ commits, not to roll back changes creating new commits. This will not remove any commit from that graph, but rather add some new ones.

Comment: all right, however i cannot recommend using push --force to a git newcomer. It is contrary to Git philosophy.

Comment: ```git push --force origin <branch name>``` is integral to many workflows and should be taught to beginners along with rebasing and resetting as soon as they have strong understanding of the fundamental add, commit, push, pull, etc. It’s not an advanced concept and it’s a very important tool in professional environments.

Comment: @codegorilla SO philosophy is to provide answers to problems. Problems should be clear, concise and solvable. Answers should be on point. I don't personally believe your is on point, since it does not remove commits.